# Remove <p>&nbsp;</p> from a String

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to remove < p >&nbsp< /p > or '< p > < /p >' from a string variable?

To illustrate, I have the following code:

```
var x = '< p > < /p > < p > < /p > I am John'; -- 2 empty paragraphs
x = x.replace('< p > < /p >',''); -- logic is to remove the empty paragraph
```

The result is it only remove the first instance of < p > < /p >. So there is one remaining paragraph in variable "x"

Is there a way to remove it? using Vanilla js

Comment: [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) or use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?retiredLocale=nl)

Comment: You can use `replaceAll` or pass a global regex to `.replace` but it's probably more robust to parse the string as HTML and filter out empty tags that way. So you don't have to handle any of the gnarly edge-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is your friend here

```
x.replace(/< p > < /p >/g, '')
```

Or split into array and join back together again

```
x.split('< p > < /p >').join('')
```